# I want to be able to run some stats on a dataframe. Using a pandas database, how can I convert object data types to int data types?

Tags: python, pandas

Although all the values in the columns I'm using are numbers, Python is telling me the data type for each is 'object'.  I can't run stats functions on them unless they are numbers.  I've tried

```
df['ColumnName'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is what I get when I run df.dtypes:

```
0
StartDate                object
EndDate                  object
Status                   object
IPAddress                object
Progress                 object
Duration (in seconds)    object
Finished                 object
RecordedDate             object
ResponseId               object
RecipientLastName        object
RecipientFirstName       object
RecipientEmail           object
ExternalReference        object
LocationLatitude         object
LocationLongitude        object
DistributionChannel      object
UserLanguage             object
TIMES TAUGHT             object
LANGUAGE                 object
NONMEMBER                object
ENGAGED                  object
BAPTIZED                 object
CONCERNS_1               object
PURPOSE_1                object
EXPERIENCE               object
Title                    object
Mname                    object
Actor                    object
Q7 - Topics              object
dtype: object
```

How can I get these data types changed?

Comment: you could write it this way:
df['column_name].astype(int)

Answer (score 0):

You have empty strings in your column that cannot be converted to `int` values

```
pd.to_numeric(df['ColumnName'])
```

will work, if the values are valid numbers or empty strings. Your column will be type `float` because the empty strings will be converted to `nan` values.

---

```
pd.to_numeric(df['ColumnName'], errors='coerce')
```

will replace every value that can't be converted to a number with `nan`.

Comment: I figure it out, I think.  `pd.to_numeric(df['colb']).astype("Int32")` seems to work; so a combo of the answers

Comment: might even be able to do `df['ColumnName'].astype("Float32").astype("Int32")`